# How to display HTML5 Video Tag in silhouette shape?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to capture the video through web application that should capture video in the shape of silhouette. Now i'm capturing like circle shape. How i can capture in the shape of silhouette? Thanks in advance.

Following are css and html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .web-cam { 
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 125px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay class="web-cam" poster="placeholder.png">

</video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        console.log("user mediaDevices");
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need The video element which i seen look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what is "the shape of silhouette"? Can you show us an example?

Comment: I would mask it instead of trying to display it in any shape. Have your regular HTML5 video element and place an SVG in front of it with the silhouette you want.

Comment: Beware that you wrote `var video = document.getElementById('video');` twice.

Comment: incidentally @dhamo dharan ~ you might want to take a look at your website - it appears to have been hijacked

Comment: @André I updated the question. Can you look at.

Comment: @Andrew accepted.

Comment: @GuillermoCarone can you give the examples?

Comment: @RamRaider Not exactly, We need to do better UI.

Comment: Check this site https://montenegrostudio.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) over a 2D context to even render your video.
However you'll need your silhouette image to have transparency.

```js
var playing = false;
    var mask = new Image();
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.muted = true;
    video.autoplay = true;
    // stacksnippets don't work well with gUM...
/*    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }
*/ 
    // so we'll use a video about volcanos from wikimedia
    video.crossOrigin = mask.crossOrigin = "anonymous";    
    video.onplaying = startRendering;
    video.onpause = stopRendering;
    
    mask.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Male_head_silhouette.svg/720px-Male_head_silhouette.svg.png";
    // wait for the image has loaded
    mask.onload = function() {
      video.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm.360p.webm";
      video.play();
    }
  
    function startRendering() {
      playing = true;
      requestAnimationFrame( render );
    }
    function stopRendering() {
      playing = false;
    }
    function render() {
      context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
      context.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, canvas.height * mask.height/mask.width, canvas.height);
      context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      if( playing ) {
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
      }
    }


document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var context = document.getElementById("still-canvas").getContext('2d');
   context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 640, 480);
});
```

```html
<!-- the video render is a canvas -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="still-canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not, exactly , i need silhouette shape inside the video element. Video capture look like profile picture.